# i have a word from my page i need to search it and replace but my code don't working

Tags: php, html, string

input

```
Input : div class="content-wrapper">    <section class="content-header">
{AAAA14}
{AAAA15}
</section></div>
```

output

```
output : 
<div class="content-wrapper">    <section class="content-header">
Main
Second 
</section></div>
```

my txt

```
txt : 
{AAAA14} Main
{AAAA15} Second
```

my code

```
$cd = '<div class="content-wrapper">    <section class="content-header">
{AAAA14}
{AAAA15}
</section></div>';

$filename = 'lang/English/texts.txt';
$g = file($filename);
$fa = explode("\n", "$cd");
$found = false;
foreach($g as $line)
{
  if(strpos($line, $fa) !== false)
  {
$f = explode("}", "$line");
  }
}
$cd = str_replace($fa, $f[1], $cd);
echo $cd;
```

the code don't working
my txt have more than 300 word

I need way to search all word in php If word == txt The txt have a,b If the word = a Give me b

Comment: `$fa` is an array, not a string. `strpos($line, $fa)` makes no sense.

Comment: if i ude an $fa[1] it's replacement 1 word not all word i need

Comment: There's no need to explode `$cd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the file into an associative array, then use `strtr()` to perform all the replacements at once.

```
<?php

$cd = '<div class="content-wrapper">    <section class="content-header">
{AAAA14}
{AAAA15}
</section></div>';

$filename = 'lang/English/texts.txt';

$lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$trans = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    list($placeholder, $replacement) = explode(' ', $line);
    $trans[$placeholder] = $replacement;
}
$cd = strtr($cd, $trans);

echo $cd;
```

Comment: the code don't working it's give me a blank page

Comment: $trans = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    [$placeholder, $replacement] = explode(' ', $line);

this make all code stop, i don't know why ??

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: The list assignment I use requires 7.1 or newer.

Comment: php 5.3.10-ubuntu

Comment: That's ancient! You need to upgrade.

Comment: i upgrade to php 7.4 it's working but not replace the word ??

Comment: friend it's replace inside the code array, not in the page 

i need the output replace

Comment: What code array? `$cd` is a string, not an array. You can convert it to an array after doing the replacement.

Comment: it's working now i fixed, my code have an error sorry, but now i have another proplem 

my txt have an 3 word at the same time like 

{AAAA1} ADMIN Panel 

how can i just split the {AAAA1} without ADMIN Panel

Comment: That seems like a completely different problem, I'm not answering it here.

Comment: why please i need the answer

Comment: thanx for everything

Comment: `$cd = preg_replace('(\{[^}]*\}).*', '$1', $cd);` to remove everything after `{XXX}` on the line.